# Which is a better way to use Props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prop

What is the difference between the two and which one is better?

```
const Person=({firstName,lastName})=>{
    return(
    <div>
    <p>{'${firstName}${lastName}'}</p>
    </div>
    )
    }
```

or

```
const Person=(props)=>{
return(
<div>
<p>{props.firstName}{props.lastName}</p>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: First method is not corect. It must to be like this: `({ firstName, lactate})`.  I'm using both. Is not any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the first one should be :-

```
const Person=({firstName,lastName})=>{
    return(
    <div>
    <p>{'${firstName}${lastName}'}</p>
    </div>
    )
    }
```

You need to destructure the properties from the `props` object which React makes for you.

There is no one good or bad here. Both can serve your purpose. Use the second one where writing `props.blabla` becomes a headache for you and where the `blabla` alone makes more sense to use.

**Edit** - @xflorin94 added a good example where you only extract the required properties from the `props` object that are relevant for current component usage and you can use `...` to get the rest of the properites and pass them to some other **ChildComponent** , **function**, **hook** etc wherever you can make use of it.

Comment: If there is no good or bad, please flag it as opinion-based.

Comment: Makes sense. But also wanted to ensure the person knows the first one is a destructure and not simply passing multiple arguments. Still you're right.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a example when I use first method:

```
class Person({firstName, lastName, ...props)} => {
 return (
   <>
     <p>{firstName}</p>
     <p>{lastName} </p>
     <ChildComponent {...props} />
   </>
 )
}
```

Instead writing all `props` to `<ChildComponent/>` i use `{...props}`. Or my `ChildComponent` doesn't have a fixed number of props etc. I mostly use that when I make reusable components.

Answer (score 1):

There is a don't have any good or bad. Actually, it's up to you. But I will be recommended to you use destructure to get access to your object properties. Cause it's clean and easy to understand doesn't have any garbage and also doesn't need to repeatedly access props.